# TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_mainValue' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

**updated2**

```
hey, 



 I moved the grid value in a new mthod carSource so the previous error I removed but right now I am getting another error,
    - is there any way I can spy on _dataSource or mock the value to pass the test cases.

     can you tell me how to fix it

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**
```

**updated code**

```
    public carSource():any{
      let car = $('#laptopMousesGrid').data('kendoGrid');
      return  grid.dataSource;
    }

  playing(evt, dropValue, values) {
      let todayDate = this.todayDate();
      //et car = $('#laptopMousesGrid').data('kendoGrid');
      //let _dataSource = car.dataSource;

          let _dataSource =this.carSource();

      let pageSize = _dataSource.pageSize();
      if(_dataSource) {

         console.log("playing--->");
      console.log("_dataSource--->" + JSON.stringify(_dataSource));
      console.log("_dataSource._data--->" + _dataSource._data);

        let carLength = _dataSource._data.length;
      }
      let filename;
      let mainValue = this.spaceService.getSeesionStorageValue();
      console.log("playing mainValue----> " + mainValue);
      if (mainValue) {
        this.userStem = mainValue.user_mainValue.SSO[0];
        this.loggedUserName = mainValue.user_mainValue.DisplayName[0];
      }
  }
```

**output**
       LOG: 'playing--->'
        LOG: '_dataSource--->{"_isScalar":true,"value":[{"carsId":"100","carsName":"uuiiuui","carsType":"TITLE","carsData":"YWZjYXJlZ2Vyamh2dmFyZWdoYnZi","notes":"","notesId":"100","fish":"100","url":"ioioioiooi","date":"ioioi","addedByName":"Kamal","userID":"6765676565","operationType":"create"},{"carsId":"101","carsName":"example.pdf","carsType":"TITLE","carsData":"john","notes":"","notesId":"101","fish":"101","url":"ioioioiooi","date":"ioioi","addedByName":"Kamal","userID":"6765676565","operationType":"create"},{"carsId":"101","carsName":"example.ppt","carsType":"TITLE","carsData":"john","notes":"","notesId":"101","fish":"101","url":"ioioioiooi","date":"ioioi","addedByName":"Kamal","userID":"6765676565","operationType":"create"}],"scheduler":null}'
        LOG: '_dataSource._data--->undefined'
        Chrome 61.0.3163 (Windows 10 0.0.0) Jasmine Unit Tests: add  FAILED
    [0]     TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
        Chrome 61.0.3163 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 69 (1 FAILED) (skipped 68) ERROR (0.56 secs / 0.422 secs)

**update**

hey I did further research the problem is with this line   **let car = $('#laptopMousesGrid').data('kendoGrid');**

when I try to print car I am getting undefined is it possible to mock the value for car or spyon so that we can set some value and pass the test case...I did some research but not sure how to proceed

My application is running fine with the below line of code

```
let mainValue=this.spaceService.getSeesionStorageValue();
```

I am able to see the value for `mainValue` in the browser where as in my test case. Providing mainValue result below

```
acr:{values: Array(1)}
amr:["ext"]
cid:"7823459-78237832387278-237823873278"
client_id:"7823459-78237832387278-237823873278"
email:"parrot.tiger.com"
scope:["openid"]
sub:"3623673267-278782378-23872872378-2378327832"
user_mainValue:{BusinessSegment:["Operations & Technical Services"], DisplayName:["pen"], Title: ["Developer"], SSO:["bndsbsbnsd"]}
zid:"6fc3c2b8-f6b4-4376-824f-9c93dfcc19a3"
```

I am not able to see.

I am getting an undefined error in my test cases LOG:

```
'playing mainValue----> undefined'.
```

Do I need to add spyon to this values?

- I am confused with spyon too.

Can you tell me how to fix it?

```or-tag-here
[0] 23 09 2017 22:28:36.720:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): C://app/components/laptops/jumping-l    LOG: '**playing mainValue----> undefined'**
[0] Chrome 60.0.3112 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 17 of 34 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 3.434 secs)
[0] 23 09 2017 22:28:36.824:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /app/components/laptops/swimming.html /
[0] 23 09 2017 22:28:36.824:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /app/components/laptops/swimming.html
[0] 23 09 2017 22:28:36.832:DEBUG [proxy]: proxying request - /app/components/laptops/swimming.html to localhost:9876
[0] 23 09 2017 22:28:36.832:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/app/components/shared/progress/progress-circle.html /
[0] 23 09 2017 22:28:36.832:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching C://app/components/shared/progress/progress-circle.html
[0] 23 09 2017 22:28:36.832:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /app/components/laptops/jumping-left-slider.html /
[0] 23 09 2017 22:28:36.832:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /app/components/laptops/jumping-left-slider.html
[0] 23 09 2017 22:28:36.836:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): C://app/components/shared/progress/progress-circle.html
    Chrome 60.0.3112 (Windows 10 0.0.0) Jasmine Unit Tests: parrot-Manage-Mouses Add Hiding Mouse FAILED
**[0]     TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_mainValue' of undefined**
[0] Chrome 60.0.3112 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 18 of 34 (2 FAILED) (0 secs / 3.562 secs)
```

**actual code**

```or-tag-here
playing(evt, dropValue, values) {
  let todayDate = this.todayDate();
  let car = $('#laptopMousesGrid').data('kendoGrid');
  let _dataSource = car.dataSource;
  let pageSize = _dataSource.pageSize();
  let carLength = _dataSource._data.length;
  let filename;
  let mainValue = this.spaceService.getSeesionStorageValue();
  console.log("playing mainValue----> " + mainValue);
  if (mainValue) {
    this.userStem = mainValue.user_mainValue.SSO[0];
    this.loggedUserName = mainValue.user_mainValue.DisplayName[0];
  }
```

**test case**

```or-tag-here
<!-- language-all: lang-or-tag-here -->

it('Add Hiding Mouse', (done) => {
  let callFirstTime: boolean = true;
  let url = spyOn(rainbow.HidingMouses.spaceService, 'getResponse').and.
  callFake(() => {
    if (callFirstTime) {
      callFirstTime = false; // Invoked by detectChanges() 
      return Observable.of([{
        "starsStem": "100",
        "starsName": "/assets/js/actualairings.json",
        "starsType": "TITLE",
        "starsData": "YWZjYXJlZ2Vyamh2dmFyZWdoYnZi",
        "jersey": "",
        "jerseyStem": "100",
        "DocRing": "100",
        "url": "/upload",
        "date": "06/27/2017",
        "addedByName": "Kamal",
        "userRing": "",
        "operationType": "create"
      }]);
    }
  });
  spyOn(rainbow.HidingMouses.carkendo, 'enableSaveMouse').and.returnValue(
    null);
  rainbow.HidingMouses.fileSelect = "text.txt";
  let values = {
    "url": "laptops/v1/stars/current",
    "columns": [],
    "title": "sky",
    "excelFileName": "ViewAiringsExport",
    "mainStem": current
  };

  rainbow.HidingMouses.playing('', '', values);
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    done();
    expect(rainbow.HidingMouses._dataSource._data.length).toEqual(3);
  });
});
```

Comment: could you please add the `console.log("playing mainValue----> " + mainValue);` result to the question?

Comment: @MohammadJavadSeyyedi jhey updated the mainValue from the browser but I was getting undefined in the testcase...when I run it in the terminal

Comment: You say that what you showed us is the result of `this.spaceService.getSeesionStorageValue()` ? then how is that 1 lien bellow that same result is undefined, saying that you see in the browser and that is the result of `this.spaceService.getSeesionStorageValue()` confuses us. The problem must be from that method. Can you also add the code to the question?  Also is this intended or just a typo that ruins all? `getSeesionStorageValue` ? Seesion instead of Session ?

Comment: @DincaAdrian  

hey I did further research the problem is with this line   **let car = $('#laptopMousesGrid').data('kendoGrid');**

when I try to print car I am getting undefined is it possible to mock the value for car or spyon so that we can set some value and pass the test case...I did some research but not sure how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming `this.spaceService.getSeesionStorageValue();` is actually reading something from the browsers session Storage, something that hasn't been added into your test browser's sessionStorage at the time of the test.  Either way, you should mock that service as its an external dependency to your unit test. A jasmine spy would work.

inject spaceService into your test like so

```
var spaceService;
beforeEach(inject(function(_spaceService_){
spaceService = _spaceService_
));
```

now mock the method on the service

```
spyOn(spaceService, 'getSeesionStorageValue');
spaceService.getSeesionStorageValue.andReturn('here is the main value');
```

now you should get a log saying `'playing mainValue----> here is the main value'`

Comment: thanks for your reply...can you tell me why we are using beforeEach so that in future for other problem I can fix it myself...

Comment: so the service is instantiated before each test and whatever state they had before is reinitialized

Comment: and whats the advantage of inject...is it not possible to achieve without inject??

Comment: to mock the service that’s being used. another way would be to (if it’s a controller) manually instantiate the item to test and pass in your mock service. look up $controller service  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller

Comment: this.spaceService is an angular service yea ?

Comment: I am not sure how to find out??

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the typo? You wrote session with two `e` instead of two `s`.

`let mainValue = this.spaceService.getSeesionStorageValue()`

I know it's dumb, but if are getting an error there, `mainValue` woul be `undefined`.

Comment: if the function didn’t exist he would get “getSeesionStorageVaue is not a function”

Comment: hey If I update the below code in my codebase I am getting the following error, can you tell me how to fix it..providing my code and eror below------>

let spaceService;
            beforeEach(inject(function(_spaceService_, ''){
                spaceService = _spaceService_
            ));

Comment: Argument of type '(_spaceService_: any) => any' is not assignable to

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like  _dataSource._data is defined from your output of _dataSource. Hope that helps!

Comment: hey thanks for your reply...can you update in my code...I am not sure how to fix it